# 'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: azure-sql-database

The new `STRING_SPLIT` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) is not available in my Azure SQL database. I had already ran `ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130` a couple days ago, and I have verified the compatibility level is indeed set to 130. `SELECT database_id, name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases`

Has anyone else been able to use the new method, and if so, did you need to do anything else to get it working?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

It was a syntax error. I was attempting to use the function as scalar and not as table valued.

Correct Syntax: `SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ');`

Comment: How would I split a string in one of my columns though? That is where the use is rather than substring indexing it and manipulating the string.

Comment: @ThinkCode you need to use 'APPLY' e.g. something a little like this maybe `SELECT t.SomeColumn, s.value FROM dbo.MyTable t CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.SomeColumn, ',') s`

Answer (score 33):

The STRING_SPLIT function is available at compatibility level 130 or higher. If your database compatibility level is lower than 130, SQL Server will not be able to find and execute STRING_SPLIT function. You can change a compatibility level of database using the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
```

EDIT:
**Note that compatibility level 150 might be default even in new Azure SQL Databases.**

For reference:

**Version** - *Highest Compatibility Level* - **Lowest Available Level**

- **Azure SQL Database**   - *160* -   **100**
- **Azure SQL Managed Instance**   - *160* -   **100**
- **SQL 2022** - *160* -   **100**
- **SQL 2019** - *150* -   **100**
- **SQL 2017** - *140* -   **100**
- **SQL 2016** - *130* -   **100**
- **SQL 2014** - *120* -   **100**
- **SQL 2012** - *110* -   **90**
- **SQL 2008** - *100* -   **80**
- **SQL 2005** - *90* -    **80**
- **SQL 2000** - *80* -    **80**

Comment: I tried to execute above query, but getting this message: Msg 15048, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, or 120.

Comment: @Prateek-Systematix Are you using SQL Server 2014? See my edit

Answer (score 19):

The `string_split` function must be placed after the `FROM` clause. Either as a table value (as in the OP's answer) **OR** use the following to split each string in a column by `","` (credit comment from @padigan):

```
SELECT * 
FROM infoTable
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(infoTable.myStrings, ',')
```

I am unsure how to name the resulting column and it takes the default name `value`

Comment: For me simply using `[VALUE] AS [categoryCodes]` allows me to rename the resulting column to whatever I like and that is in-line with the code that you have, you would just need to write out all columns as opposed to using the asterisk.