# Insert comma delimited ids into a table

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to insert records into a SQL Server table. The client send ids I need to insert into a specific column in the table:

```
(2,4,123,1357,1234,5657,753);
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10581814/500105) function I'm splitting the comma delimited string, but not sure how to insert it to the table along with the other columns

I need to create something that will generate inserts such as:

```
insert into table_name (id,column_2,column_3) values (2, column_s_some_value, column_3_some_value);
insert into table_name (id,column_2,column_3) values (4, column_s_some_other_value, column_3_some_value);
insert into table_name (id,column_2,column_3) values (123, column_s_some_value, column_3_some_value);
ETC...
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: SQL server 2016? or older?

Comment: It's actually on Azure

Comment: You could cross join to [table valued function string_spilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616831/string-split-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name) and write dynamic SQL to do the insert with values (),(),(),()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the split function is a Table-Valued Function, which means it can be treated as a table, and you can do an INSERT..SELECT

```
insert into table_name (id,column_2,column_3)
SELECT s.item, column_s_some_value, column_3_some_value
FROM Split(@input_string, ',') s
{JOINS if needed to get other column values}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to split strings, the most efficient way to get that done is through the use of the tally table as outlined [here by Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). I'd strongly suggest you use this method in just about any version of SQL Server.